# Ruby on Rails: Find a record by an attribute not an id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm very new to rails so please be patient with me.

In short I'm trying to create a form in which guests to a wedding can enter a simple code (`invite_code`) and then RSVP. The from should take the `invite_code` and then take the use straight to the correct `invites#show` view.

So far so good, but I'm stuck trying to get rails to find a record by something other than and `id`, I want to find by `invite_code`. Say I've got an `Invite` with an `id` of 4 and an `invite_id` of 1234, the form is finding the correct record when I enter '4' into the from but not '1234'. Here's some code to explain:

**routes.rb**

```
get 'invites/search', to: 'invites#show', controller: :invites
```

**form**

```
...
<%= form_tag invites_search_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= label_tag :invite_code, "#" %>
  <%= text_field_tag :invite_code, nil %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
<% end %>
...
```

**invites_controller**

```
...
  def show
    if params.has_key?(:invite_code)
      @invite = Invite.find(params[:invite_code])
    else
      @invite = Invite.find(params[:id])
    end
  end
...
```

**rake routes output**

```
       Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                   Controller#Action
   info_index GET    /info/index(.:format)                         info#index
      invites GET    /invites(.:format)                            invites#index
              POST   /invites(.:format)                            invites#create
   new_invite GET    /invites/new(.:format)                        invites#new
  edit_invite GET    /invites/:id/edit(.:format)                   invites#edit
       invite GET    /invites/:id(.:format)                        invites#show
              PATCH  /invites/:id(.:format)                        invites#update
              PUT    /invites/:id(.:format)                        invites#update
              DELETE /invites/:id(.:format)                        invites#destroy
```

invites_search GET    /invites/search(.:format)                     invites#show
             root GET    /                                             info#index

**URL example**

```
.../invites/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&invite_code=1234

"utf8"=>"✓", "invite_code"=>"1234", "id"=>"search"
```

The application seems to be ignoring the `invite_id` part of if statement in the controller...

Any help appreciated, it's taken me a long time to get this far...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a couple of options. `find_by_invite_code` will return you the first match:

```
Invite.find_by_invite_code(params[:invite_code]) # First match or nil
```

While `where` will give you all the matches as an Array

```
Invite.where(invite_code: params[:invite_code]) # Array of matches. May be empty
```

You can also use the following syntax for `find_by`:

```
Invite.find_by(invite_code: params[:invite_code]) # First match or nil
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you happen to know why if I change the route to `invite#edit` and switch the 'edit' action in the controller I get a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in InvitesController#show` error? It doesn't make sense as I seem to have changed the applicable code to direct to 'edit' not 'show'...

Comment: @lkemitchll - Did you restart the server? I believe routes are only parsed at boot (BICBW).

Comment: Yes, I still get the same exception "
  def show
    [at]invite = Invite.find(params[:id])
  end". Which would suggest it's still somehow routing to 'show'.

Comment: Looking at your URL example, I think Rails is matching `/invites/search?stuff` against `GET /invites/:id`. It's probably related to the order of your routes file. If you can't figure it out, open another question.

Comment: Ok, Here's the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27861734/ruby-on-rails-route-not-updating-correctly

Answer (score 1):

`find` uses `id` field by default, use `where` instead

```
if params.has_key?(:invite_code)
  @invite = Invite.where(invite_code: params[:invite_code]).first
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...
  def show
    if params.has_key?(:invite_code)
      @invite = Invite.find_by(invite_code: params[:invite_code])
      # find_by argument: value
      # returns first match or nil
      # same as find, where find searches by id
      # Invite.find_by_invite_code params[:invite_code] is deprecated  
    else
      @invite = Invite.find params[:id]
    end
  end
...
```