# Ruby on Rails: Route not updating correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got the following route defined:

```
get 'invites/search', to: 'invites#edit', controller: :invites
```

Which I changed from:

```
get 'invites/search', to: 'invites#show', controller: :invites
```

The controller is as follows:

```
def show
  @invite = Invite.find(params[:id])
end

...

def edit
  # If the request is a search containing an 'invite_code'
  if params.has_key?(:invite_code)
    @invite = Invite.where(invite_code: params[:invite_code]).first
  else
    @invite = Invite.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in InvitesController#show

Couldn't find Invite with 'id'=search

Extracted source (around line #7):         

6  def show
7    @invite = Invite.find(params[:id])
8  end

def new
```

Which suggests the route hasn't updated?

Here's the rake route:

```
invites_search GET    /invites/search(.:format)                     invites#edit
```

I've tried restarting the server, but I'm not really sure what to do now? How can I get the route to go to 'edit' not 'show'?

Thanks,

LM.

EDIT:

Here's the form from the index page:

```
<%= form_tag invites_search_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= label_tag :invite_code, "#" %>
  <%= text_field_tag :invite_code, nil %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
<% end %>
```

EDIT 2:

See here for the explantion of what I'm trying to achieve with this code:
[Ruby on Rails: Find a record by an attribute not an id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27858709/ruby-on-rails-find-a-record-by-an-attribute-not-an-id)

Comment: Show me the link from the index view please, or how are you trying to acces that method

Comment: Look at sections 2.10.1 Adding Member Routes, 2.10.2 Adding Collection Routes on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: @Andru1989 I've updated the question above with the simple form i'm using.

Comment: why don't you try to acces that field this way @invite = Invite.find(params[:invite_code]) because in the view you are passing the text_field_tag with :invite_code rather than :id, it depends of what you want to pass from the view text_field because with Invite.find(params[:invite_code]) you make the query with the id table field

Comment: @Andru1989 Maybe, but that doesn't really explain why the form directs to 'show' not 'edit', Unless i'm being dim.

Comment: I've ran that exactly code get 'invites/search', to: 'invites#edit', controller: :invites and works ok, can you send me the routes.rb file

Comment: @Andru1989 http://pastebin.com/qqNDiGtG

Comment: Look at that http://pastebin.com/nLxEStG6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68493/discussion-between-lkemitchll-and-andru1989).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try to create another name for that method because `resources :invites` always generate the complete CRUD so maybe it's a conflict

Try something like that in routes.rb

```
resources :invites do
  resources :guests
  collection do
    get 'search'
  end
end
```

Then you call it in the form like that

```
<%= form_tag search_invites_path, method: :get do %>
```